# Laptop fan speed abnormally high after installing 13.04, Unity doesn't load after installing and removing fglrx

Tags: 13.04, fglrx, fan

I have a Toshiba Satellite P300-1FO laptop, and I recently deleted my 12.10 and freshly installed 13.04.

The fan speed becomes abnormally high after a short time operating the computer. The CPU usage is low, so I don't believe it is over-heating.

I followed the first answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04) and ran the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw smartmontools ethtool
```

I didn't run any other configuration command, I just wanted to check the temperature, which seems reasonable:

```
tlp-stat -t 
--- TLP 0.3.9 --------------------------------------------

+++ Temperatures
CPU temp               =    56 [°C]
Fan speed              = (not available)
```

**Edit 1:**
Following the first answer, I installed lm-sensors, and got the following output when running "sensors":

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +57.0°C  (crit = +104.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +53.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +54.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

I then installed fglrx, and when I ran "aticonfig", I got the following output:

```
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

**Edit 2**: The following is the output of tlp-stat:

```
--- TLP 0.3.9 --------------------------------------------

+++ Configured Settings: /etc/default/tlp
TLP_ENABLE=1
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1
NMI_WATCHDOG=0
DISK_DEVICES="sda sdb"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC=max_performance
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT=min_power
PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=performance
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=high
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=1
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=5
WOL_DISABLE=Y
SOUND_POWER_SAVE=1
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=0
BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto
RUNTIME_PM_ALL=0
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0

+++ System Info
System         = TOSHIBA PSPCCE-053021PT Satellite P300
BIOS           = V3.00   
Release        = Ubuntu 13.04
Kernel         = 3.8.0-19-generic x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic root=UUID=23776272-8db7-4faa-8308-95d6950371a5 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

+++ System Status
TLP power save = enabled
power source   = ac

+++ Processor
CPU Model      = Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T9550  @ 2.66GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2667000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2667000 2666000 2133000 1600000 800000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2667000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2667000 2666000 2133000 1600000 800000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost                  = 1
/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0

+++ Undervolting
PHC kernel not available.

+++ Temperatures
CPU temp               =    57 [°C]
Fan speed              = (not available)

+++ File System
/proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode               =     0
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs =  1500
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs    =  1500
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio               =    10
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio    =     5
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/age_buffer_centisecs  = (not available)
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfssyncd_centisecs    = (not available)
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfsbufd_centisecs     = (not available)

+++ Storage Devices
/dev/sda:
          Model     = Hitachi HTS543232L9SA00                 
          Firmware  = FB4OC43C
          APM Level = 254
          Status    = active/idle
          scheduler = deadline

        SMART info:
            4 Start_Stop_Count          =     4571 
            5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct     =        1 
            9 Power_On_Hours            =    15888 [h]
          193 Load_Cycle_Count          =    50269 
          194 Temperature_Celsius       =       33 (Min/Max 13/56)  [°C]

/dev/sdb:
          Model     = TOSHIBA MK3252GSX                       
          Firmware  = LV010M  
          APM Level = 254
          Status    = active/idle
          scheduler = deadline

        SMART info:
            4 Start_Stop_Count          =    18903 
            5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct     =        0 
            9 Power_On_Hours            =    14379 [h]
          193 Load_Cycle_Count          =   100836 
          194 Temperature_Celsius       =       39 (Min/Max 15/70)  [°C]


+++ SATA Aggressive Link Power Management
/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host4/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host5/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance

+++ PCIe Active State Power Management
/sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policy = default (using bios preferences)

+++ Radeon Graphics
/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method = profile
/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile = high

+++ Wireless
bluetooth = on
wifi      = on
wwan      = none (no device)

wlan0(iwlwifi): power management = off

+++ Audio
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save            = 1
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller = Y

+++ Battery Status
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer                   = SANYO
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name                     = NS3P3SZNJSWR
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full_design             =   4000 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full                    =   2966 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_now                     =   2966 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/current_now                    =      0 [mA]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status                         = Full

+++ Runtime Power Management
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control = on   (0x060000 Host bridge)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/power/control = on   (0x060400 PCI bridge)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1a.0/power/control = on   (0x0c0300 USB controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1a.1/power/control = on   (0x0c0300 USB controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1a.2/power/control = on   (0x0c0300 USB controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1a.7/power/control = on   (0x0c0320 USB controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1b.0/power/control = on   (0x040300 Audio device)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/control = on   (0x060400 PCI bridge)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.1/power/control = on   (0x060400 PCI bridge)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.3/power/control = on   (0x060400 PCI bridge)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control = on   (0x0c0300 USB controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.1/power/control = on   (0x0c0300 USB controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.2/power/control = on   (0x0c0300 USB controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.7/power/control = on   (0x0c0320 USB controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1e.0/power/control = on   (0x060401 PCI bridge)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control = on   (0x060100 ISA bridge)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control = on   (0x010601 SATA controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/control = on   (0x0c0500 SMBus)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control = on   (0x030000 VGA compatible controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/power/control = on   (0x040300 Audio device)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/power/control = on   (0x028000 Network controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/power/control = on   (0x020000 Ethernet controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0a:01.0/power/control = on   (0x0c0010 FireWire (IEEE 1394))
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0a:01.2/power/control = on   (0x080501 SD Host controller)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0a:01.3/power/control = on   (0x018000 Mass storage controller)

+++ USB
tlp usb autosuspend = enabled
tlp usb blacklist   = (not configured)

Bus 002 Device 003 ID 04f2:b008 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB 2.0 Camera (uvcvideo)
Bus 006 Device 002 ID 046d:c517 control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser (usbhid)
Bus 008 Device 002 ID 0930:0508 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Toshiba Corp. Integrated Bluetooth HCI (btusb)
Bus 001 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 002 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 003 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0001 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub (hub)
Bus 004 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0001 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub (hub)
Bus 005 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0001 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub (hub)
Bus 006 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0001 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub (hub)
Bus 007 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0001 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub (hub)
Bus 008 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0001 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub (hub)
```

After installing fglrx and rebooting, the resolution decreased and Unity did not load. I removed fglrx by running "sudo apt-get remove fglrx", and after I rebooted, the computer returned to its full resolution, but Unity still doesn't load.

So now I have two problems:

1. Fan speed does not decrease
2. Unity doesn't load, I have to use the terminal for everything

Please advise.

Comment: would you please post the output of > sudo tlp-stat

Comment: I have check specs of your laptop have you installed Graphics Processor  ATI Radeon HD 3650  ???

Comment: I have posted the output of "sudo tlp-stat". I installed "fglrx" for my ATI graphics, but after the reboot, the resolution decreased and Unity did not load, as per my Edit 2 above.

Comment: In Section no 3 Processor and Frequency Scaling use powersave on both ac/bat ... and check settings /etc/default/tlp  = RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=high , = RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low ....but 1st you need to fix the driver ....( install driver ) check blogs on how to install ATI drivers ...

Comment: you need to understand most of tlp settings will active on battery power ..your issue is not with tlp..your issue is with the drivers ....you are on ac power so its nothing to do with tlp...

Answer (score 1):

you should install lm-sensors pack and check your GPU (graphics card)...

try to install proprietary ati or nvidia driver. Its more efficient in some configs. (i have ati hd 5470 and open source driver makes my card overheat -around 80 C all time- and in low performance mode is too low in performance :) )

install fglrx or flglrx-updates from software center or software sources in control panel/ system settings...

**Edit:**
you can use 'software-center' through terminal and there was a bug in 12.10 (i have got it too) about unity and FGLRX
install CCSM (compizconfig-settings-manager) and disable Sync to Vblank in OpenGL plugin... then restart system or just log out and in.
It should come back (unity)

about FGLRX, you can check it (temp) by aticonfig --odgt 
also disabling framebuffer object in ccsm can reduce tempature and gpu usage.
try look at workarounds plugin and play with these settings.
After ALL installation and un-installation of graphics card driver dont forget to restart entire system.

for unity (again) try unity and compiz --replace commands
and if your graphics card doesnt seem to respond all of these, use fglrx-updates package...

I saw the 'no unity' bug in 12.10 but not in 13.04. good luck...

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please advise on how to proceed.

Comment: mate, i have edited too sorry for late answer